# sqlite value not assigning to variable

Tags: android, sqlite, expo, react-native

I'm currently working with React native mobile application, on this process I use SQLite to store data locally within the phone the problem is I have assigned a variable `getToken` which need to be filled by the token I stored in SQLite DB. below is the method i tried and it always returns the default value.

```
function getTest() {
  let getToken = 'ABC';
  db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Login', [], (tx, result) => {
     getToken = result.rows.item(0).access_token;
    });
  });

  return getToken;
}
```

Comment: This is because transaction and executesql are async methods. Try using await or resolve a promise inside executeSql callback

Comment: @SaachiTech can you put an answer?

Comment: Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56732063

Comment: Thanks, @SaachiTech. i added the answer based on your oppinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of transaction and executeSQL are async methods. Try using await or resolve a promise inside executeSQL callback. i solved this issue as follows

```
async function returnToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Login', [], (tx, result) => {
        let accessToken = result.rows.item(0).access_token;
        resolve(accessToken);
      });
    });
  });
}

async function (config){
    let token = await returnToken();
    console.log('token', token);
}
```